# cannot find symbol import dagger.hilt.android.internal.Contexts

Tags: unit-testing, dagger-hilt

I am trying to write test for **Dagger_Hilt** (hilt-android-testing:2.38.1), but unfortunately this error is occurring when I run the test. I can't understand what's the problem. It would be of much help if anyone could help me to resolve this error.

> cannot find symbol
> import dagger.hilt.android.internal.Contexts;
> ^
>
> symbol:   class Contexts   location: package
> dagger.hilt.android.internal

The ShoppingDaoTest.kt class:

```
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @SmallTest
    @HiltAndroidTest
    class ShoppingDaoTest {

       @get:Rule
       var hileRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

       @get:Rule
       var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

       @Inject
       @Named("test_db")
       lateinit var database: ShoppingItemDatabase
   
       private lateinit var dao: ShoppingDao

       @Before
       fun setup() {
         hileRule.inject()
         dao = database.shoppingDao()
       }

      @After
      fun teardown() {
        database.close()
      }

  
    @Test
    fun insertShoppingItem() = runBlockingTest {
        val shoppingItem = ShoppingItem("name", 1, 1f, "url", id = 1)
        dao.insertShoppingItem(shoppingItem)

        val allShoppingItems = dao.observeAllShoppingItems().getOrAwaitValue()

        assertThat(allShoppingItems).contains(shoppingItem)

    }
}
```

The TestModule.kt class :

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object TestAppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("test_db")
    fun provideinMemoryDb(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ) = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, ShoppingItemDatabase::class.java)
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()


}
```

The HiltTestRunner.kt class :

```
class  HiltTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(
        cl: ClassLoader?,
        className: String?,
        context: Context?
    ): Application {
       // return super.newApplication(cl, className, context)
         return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

and the build.gradle setting :

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.mypackage.name.HiltTestRunner"
  }
}

 dependencies{
  ...
 
      // Local Unit Tests
implementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.2.1"
testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0"

// Instrumented Unit Tests
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.12.1"
androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.2.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0"
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1'

kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1'


 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, looking into my code I noticed that my dagger-hilt classpath project was on 2.36 so I updated to 2.38.1 and reviewed if all hilt dependencies had same version (otherwise error occurs again and again) finally you must clear & rebuild project. I hope this solution works for you !

classpath plugin:

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"
```

dagger hilt:

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
```

dagger hilt test:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1'
kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1'
```